# Convert image from telegram server to sticker in python telegram API

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've been trying to implement a bot that will get an image from the telegram chat, will convert it into sticker format, and then send it back in the chat. How exactly does this conversion take place provided that the image sent is of the right size?

[the image of the method I've been trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUnjS.png)

This obviously doesn't work, so please help me.

Comment: please add the code directly to the question, rather than just an image

Answer (score 0):

Even if you convert it into a [sticker](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#stickers)

No use for that

It must be in `set` to be saved and used in other chats